# Modal script to stop/pause embedded video playback when closed

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to modify this javascript to stop/pause multiple embedded video playback when the modal is closed. Many attempts to merge different events to no avail. Thank you for your assistance.

```js
et modalBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll("#video_1")];
      modalBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
          let modal = btn.getAttribute("data-modal");
          document.getElementById(modal).style.display = "block";
          document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
          document.body.style.height = "100%";
        };
      });
      let closeBtns = [...document.querySelectorAll(".close")];
      closeBtns.forEach(function (btn) {
        btn.onclick = function () {
          let modal = btn.closest(".modal");
          modal.style.display = "none";
            
            // Start NOT WORKING
            document.querySelector('.yt-video').each(function(){
            var el_src = document.querySelector(this).attr("src");
            document.querySelector(this).attr("src",el_src);
            });
            // End NOT WORKING
            
          document.body.style.overflow = "auto"; 
          document.body.style.height = "auto";
        };
      });
      window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target.className === "modal") {
          event.target.style.display = "none";
          document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
          document.body.style.height = "auto";

        }
  };
```

```html
<div id="video_1" data-modal="modalOne"><img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/DraPh7MDxtyd1sUUeOgDjI6muf8=/0x146:2040x1214/fit-in/1200x630/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/10581345/acastro_180403_1777_youtube_0001.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;height:auto;"></div>
<!-- Start Modal -->
<div id="modalOne" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content"> <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;">
      <iframe class="yt-video" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Z8eXaXoUJRQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you are trying to use jQuery functions in a code that is not jQuery. Example: `.attr`, `.each` (and others probably). Also `querySelector` only return the first matching element so there would be no `.each` method on the result. Is this some code you found somewhere ?

Comment: Also, if you want to "merge" event handlers, then I would suggest not doing that and use `addEventListener('click', handler)` multiple time instead of assigning to `onclick` property

Comment: Thank you.. The example was found here, https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-create-a-popup-form-using-javascript.html I have achieved the function using a separate jQuery snippet but was hoping to use a cleaner and all javascript solution.